# Unable to convert HTML to PDF in Internet Explorer using jsPdf library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Last 3 days, I have been digging into it but didn't taste much success. I'm able to convert HTML to PDF in other browsers, but not in IE. I've tried on IE 9 and IE 11 versions.

Based on the research I've done, it is found out that fromHtml function is not supported for IE, and hence we need to use Downloadify library. So even after referring to various sites about the way it needs to used, I still stuck up in "Downloadify is undefined" error. I'm not able to understand what wrong I'm doing.

Could someone please help me? I'm badly stuck. I need a working example with all the necessary files.

Please help.